# AngularJS Accordian Tag not working

Tags: angularjs, netbeans, accordion

I am new to AngularJS and tried to learn the tutorial/code sample from the link below.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I downloaded the latest version of Angularjs script and the bootstrap as suggested on above link and placed the code something as below just to test it out in Netbeans.

[image]

Also, the code I have written as below.

[image]

but it is throwing an error as below. Also when I hit control+Space (intellisense), it is not even listing Accordion tag.

[image]

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add bootstrap module to your app

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```